# Filtered Synchronized Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I created a filtered data extension from the SYNCHRONIZED Contact data extension from Salesforce.
There were many fields on that DE, but only one EMAIL type field and I used the Contact ID as related to Subscriber on SubscriberKey.
I tried a Guided Send to that filtered DE and it didn't work...
Then I created a new DE populated with a query with only the 2 or 3 fields I need, and then the send worked...

Would you have any idea of why it failed with a filtered synchronized DE ?
Is there a restriction in SFMC with synchronized DE or filtered synchronized DE?

Comment: are you using the Classic Email or the new Email Studio? it should work in the Email Studio - but since you said "Guided Send", I guess you are using Classic Email which won't work in that case

Comment: Hello, I used the new Email Studio. Actually, i used the feature/button Send on an Email (In Email studio > Email > Content). So i am surprised that the send to a FILTERED SYNCHRONIZED data extension didn't work...!

Comment: BTW, you don't need to manually establish the send relationship, so maybe you didn't create the filtered DE properly? `I used the Contact ID as related to Subscriber on SubscriberKey` --> you shouldn't even have to do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to correctly filter and send to Synchronized Data Extensions:

1. Go to Synchronized Data Extensions and click on the Filter icon in the Actions column next to the Data Extension you wish to use:

[image]

2. Define your filter and click on Save & Build
3. Go to your email in Email Studio and click on Send
4. In the Select Audience tab, select your filtered Data Extension and drag and drop it in the Targeted Audience window
5. Fill in all other details if necessary, confirm that all information is correct and send

On the screenshot below, I did exactly that, using a filtered Synchronized Data Extension:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This was how I proceed. I just used the "Contact ID" as related to Subscriber on SubscriberKey instead of the default "_ContactKey", but it should be the same ID. Finally, after your message I modified the filtered sync DE to put back the initial default "_ContactKey" (as related to Subscriber on SubscriberKey) and then it finally worked...! So now, I won't change field. Maybe that was why it didn't work (even though - again - "_ContactKey" and the "Id" in the sync Contact DE should be exactly the same id...!

Comment: ContactID is the system ID while ContactKey is the same as SubscriberKey. Do not confuse Marketing Cloud’s ContactID with the Sales/Service Cloud Contact ID, they are two completely different things. Glad it worked!

Comment: OK thank you for your precision. But in that case, they are exactly the same. The ContactKey of the Synchronized Contact data extension when there is the MC connector should be the Salesforce Contact ID, right ?

Comment: Marketing Cloud ContactID != Salesforce Contact ID. Maybe this will clarify what I mean: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193008/what-is-the-difference-between-primary-key-contact-id-contact-key-subscriber-k